# Prevent URL Parameters for Session Tracking programmatically

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am working on  Spring Project and am I am trying to prevent URL Parameters for Session Tracking programmatically. This is my code

```
import org.auctions.Config.MvcConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import web.SessionListenerWithMetrics;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
        servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
        servletContext.addListener(SessionListenerWithMetrics.class);
        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**My question** is, are there any other approaches to do this programmatically. I am not sure if this a proper way,

Can someone help me to put this line of code in the right place

```
servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your mind about having to be programmatically, in application.properties:

```
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the session tracking mode in web.xml

```
<web-app>
....other stuff
        <session-config>
             <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
             <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This will disable url rewriting by the server

Comment: As the title said I am interesting to do it programmtically .